# mxnet-cu102mkl==1.6.0 disappered from pypi today, why?

Tags: python, pypi, mxnet

Looks like that version disappeared recently:

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mxnet-cu102mkl==1.6.0 (from versions: 1.6.0.post0)
11:39:11
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for mxnet-cu102mkl==1.6.0
```

The top hit from Google for `mxnet-cu102mkl` https://pypi.org/project/mxnet-cu102mkl/1.6.0/ is a 404.

There is a `1.6.0.post0` available, apparently added "about 3 hours ago", but I'm a little afraid to switch to it, since such change without a visible explanation smells like an attack attempt.

Comment: FWIW, Following the instructions for Windows in the issue mentioned below by Dustin does seem to help here:

 pip install mxnet-cu102mkl==1.6.0 -f https://dist.mxnet.io/python

Answer (score 1):

PyPI admin here. The `1.6.0.post0` release was uploaded by the same maintainers.

See also https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/17963

Comment: Thanks Dustin. I did see the issue you linked to, but it's a few months old and only seems to concern the windows package.